# cartesian product and complement operator proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am a first-semester physics student and I am currently working on a problem I can't find the solution for:

Given that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$ proove that:

$ (U \times V) \backslash (A \times B) = ((U \backslash A) \times V) \cup (U \times V \backslash B)) $

Now, I do understand what both sides of the equation "do", but I can't get from

$\{ \forall (x,y) | (x \in U \wedge y \in V \} \cap \{\forall (x,y) | (x \notin A \wedge y \notin B \} $

to

$\{ \forall (x,y) | ((x \in U \wedge y \in V \backslash B) \vee (x \in U \backslash A  \wedge y \in V \}$

Human logic tells me this is exactly the same, but I don't find a way to write it.
Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Should the right side of your equation be $((U \backslash A) \times V) \cup (U \times (V \backslash B))?$  Here's a hint: show that, for all $s,$ $s$ is a member of the set on the left-hand side iff $s$ is a member of the set on the right-hand side.

Comment: Of course, I fixed it.

Comment: So, do you mean a table?

Comment: I meant: $s\in (U \times V) \backslash (A \times B)$ iff $s$ is an ordered pair $(u,v)$ such that $u\in U, v\in V,$ and $(u,v)\not\in A\times B,$ and then proceed with further logical equivalences, unravelling what it means one step at a time.